# A ListView of checkboxes in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qitemdelegate, qlistview

I want to display a QListView where each item is a checkbox with some label. The checkboxes should be visible at all times. One way I can think of is using a custom delegate and QAbstractListModel. Are there simpler ways? Can you provide the simplest snippet that does this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are writing your own model, just include the `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable`
flag in the return value from the `flags()` method, and ensure that you return
a valid value for the `Qt.CheckStateRole` from the `data()` method.

If you use the `QStandardItemModel` class, include the `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable`
flag in those you pass to each item's `setFlags()` method, and set the check
state for the `Qt.CheckStateRole` with its `setData()` method.

In an interactive Python session, type the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

model = QStandardItemModel()
item = QStandardItem("Item")
item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
item.setData(QVariant(Qt.Checked), Qt.CheckStateRole)
model.appendRow(item)

view = QListView()
view.setModel(model)
view.show()
```

Answer (score 24):

I ended up using the method provided by [David Boddie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61047/david-boddie) in the PyQt mailing list. Here's a working snippet based on his code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
from random import randint


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

model = QStandardItemModel()

for n in range(10):                   
    item = QStandardItem('Item %s' % randint(1, 100))
    check = Qt.Checked if randint(0, 1) == 1 else Qt.Unchecked
    item.setCheckState(check)
    item.setCheckable(True)
    model.appendRow(item)


view = QListView()
view.setModel(model)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note: changed the call of `setData` with a check role to `setCheckState` and used `setCheckable` instead of flags.

Comment: what signals (if any) are emitted when such item/checkbox is toggled?

Comment: to answer myself, `model.itemChanged` can be used, as shown here: http://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-qlistview-and-qstandarditemmodel/

Comment: what signals (if any) are emitted when such item/checkbox is highlight but no toggled?